# Process.Start() and user impersonation

Tags: c#, .net, iis, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a MSI installer custom action which calls `Process.Start()` to run a batch file which internally does lot of operations and finally calls `iisreset`. But on few computers, this is failing with access denied error. Interestingly, the user running the MSI can do `iisreset` from a command prompt. It only fails when executed through my process.

So I am wondering, is `Process.Start()` spawning new process as the current user with less privileges? If yes, how can I say to run as the same user with all privileges user has? Can any one help me to understand this better and diagnose on why this fails.

```
MSI created using : Visual Studio 2008
Server : Windows Server 2008
UAC Status : Off
```

**Error Message**

> Restart attempt failed. Access denied,
>   you must be an administrator of the
>   remote computer to use this command.
>   Either have your account added to the
>   administrator local group of the
>   remote computer or to the domain
>   administrator global group

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the MSI running under admin mode? If not it probabvly won't work. why would windows let an installer do that without requiring admin mode?

Comment: @DustinDavis : yes. as I said if a user can do `iisreset` from command prompt, which essentially means that he has rights to do the action.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the [msidbCustomActionTypeNoImpersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa368069) flag (`0x800`) on your custom action to avoid issues with the User Access Control feature of recent Windows systems.

See [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rflaming/archive/2006/09/23/768248.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So does this mean a custom action modifying system will always run under less privileged mode?

Comment: @Appu, that depends. Non-impersonating custom actions will run with `Local System` privileges, but impersonating custom actions will run with the privileges of the current user, which will be lower if UAC comes into play, even if the current user is a member of the `Administrators` group.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you how I can set this property?

Comment: @Appu, that depends on your setup technology (VS setup and deployment projects, WiX, Wise, InstallShield, InnoSetup, etc.). Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio setup and custom action DLL is written using C#

Comment: Also, I just had a quick check and UAC is OFF on the computers. I am wondering will this happen even if UAC is OFF?

Comment: @Appu, there's supposed to be a `NoImpersonate` custom action property in Visual Studio (set to `true` by default, which would be all right), but I can't find it in the VS2010 property pane. Can you check in your version (or in the `vdproj` file)?

Comment: @Appu, that should not happen if UAC is turned off. There's something else going on here. The machines involved *do* have IIS installed and running, right?

Comment: Thanks again. Yes the machines have IIS installed and running. As I said they can do `iisreset` from a command prompt. But not through MSI

Comment: BTW, this is the full error message : `Restart attempt failed. Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to use this command. Either have your account added to the administrator local group of the remote computer or to the domain administrator global group`